# C++ multidimensional array trying to check values for a win?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm very new to coding and have hit a confusing spot...I have made a very basic ticTacToe game and when I am trying to check the value of the array to see if there are 3 in a row it is not grabbing the values (or maybe it is but im out of scope??).

Just wondering how I would go about checking the value of my multi array?

Here is the code.

user.cpp // check win function

```
void User::checkForWin()
{
board board;//construct board

if ((board.ticTacToeBoard[0][0] == getUser1Char()) && (board.ticTacToeBoard[0][1] == getUser1Char()) &&
    (board.ticTacToeBoard[0][2] == getUser1Char()))//Check array values to see if they win.  PROBLEM AREA
{
    std::cout << getUserName(_user1Char) << "You Are The Winner!" << std::endl;
    exit(0);
}
```

User.cpp // Game loop

```
void User::userGo(char userGo)
{
board board;                //Construct board
board.initBoard();          //Initilize board

int quitGame = 1;           //sets value of quit game loop...This isnt working either but a minor issue for now as im just using exit(); until i figure it out

while (quitGame == 1)       //game loop
{
    while (userGo == 'G')   //loop to swap user goes
    {
invalid1:                   //goto return point if user1 enters an invalid character.
cout << getUserName('A') << " Please enter a letter between A and I or Q for quit" << endl;

        char player1Input; //
        cin >> player1Input;

        if ((player1Input == 'Q') || (player1Input == 'A') || (player1Input == 'B') ||      // If player input equals
            (player1Input == 'C') || (player1Input == 'D') || (player1Input == 'E') ||      // any of these values
            (player1Input == 'F') || (player1Input == 'G') || (player1Input == 'H') ||      // then run for loop
            (player1Input == 'I'))
        {
            for (int iii = 0; iii < 3; iii++)                                   // Looping through tictactoe board values
            {                                                                   // values are set to A through I
                for (int jjj = 0; jjj < 3; jjj++)                               // as there are 9 places in the array
                {
                    switch (player1Input)                                       // Checking user input against and placing into array in relevant spot.
                    {                                                           // *Find More elegant way to right this maybe with a loop.
                        case 'Q':
                            cout << "Thanks for Playing! " << endl;
                            quitGame = 2;
                            exit(0);
                        case 'A':
                            board.ticTacToeBoard[0][0] = 'X';
                            break;
                        case 'B':
                            board.ticTacToeBoard[0][1] = 'X';
                            break;
                        case 'C':
                            board.ticTacToeBoard[0][2] = 'X';
                            break;
                        case 'D':
                            board.ticTacToeBoard[1][0] = 'X';
                            break;
                        case 'E':
                            board.ticTacToeBoard[1][1] = 'X';
                            break;
                        case 'F':
                            board.ticTacToeBoard[1][2] = 'X';
                            break;
                        case 'G':
                            board.ticTacToeBoard[2][0] = 'X';
                            break;
                        case 'H':
                            board.ticTacToeBoard[2][1] = 'X';
                            break;
                        case 'I':
                            board.ticTacToeBoard[2][2] = 'X';
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
else                                                                
        {
            cout << "Sorry ";
            getUserName('A');                                                    // If none of the values are correct print out wrong value statement
            cout << " This is not a valid move." << endl;                        // and send the user back to the invalid1 Marker.
            goto invalid1;
        }

        checkForWin();                                                          // Check for win - PROBLEM AREA
        board.printBoard();                                                     // Print board for user2 visual
        userGo = 'F';                                                           // swap to User2's Go.
    }
    while (userGo == 'F')                   //loop to swap user goes
        {
invalid2:                                       //goto return point if user2 enters an invalid character.
    cout << getUserName('B') << " Please enter a letter between A and I or press Q to quit." << endl;

        char player2Input;
        cin >> player2Input;
        if ((player2Input == 'Q') || (player2Input == 'A') || (player2Input == 'B') ||      // If player input equals
            (player2Input == 'C') || (player2Input == 'D') || (player2Input == 'E') ||      // any of these values
            (player2Input == 'F') || (player2Input == 'G') || (player2Input == 'H') ||      // then run for loop        
            (player2Input == 'I'))
        {
            for (int iii = 0; iii < 3; iii++)                                               // Looping through tictactoe board values
            {                                                                               // values are set to A through I
                for (int jjj = 0; jjj < 3; jjj++)                                           // as there are 9 places in the array
                {
                    switch (player2Input)                                                           // Checking user input against and placing into array in relevant spot.
                    {                                                                               // *Find More elegant way to right this maybe with a loop.
                        case 'Q':
                            cout << "Thanks for Playing" << endl;
                            quitGame = 2;
                            exit(0);
                            break;
                        case 'A':
                            board.ticTacToeBoard[0][0] = 'O';

                            break;
                        case 'B':
                            board.ticTacToeBoard[0][1] = 'O';
                            break;
                        case 'C':
                            board.ticTacToeBoard[0][2] = 'O';
                            break;
                        case 'D':
                            board.ticTacToeBoard[1][0] = 'O';
                            break;
                        case 'E':
                            board.ticTacToeBoard[1][1] = 'O';
                            break;
                        case 'F':
                            board.ticTacToeBoard[1][2] = 'O';
                            break;
                        case 'G':
                            board.ticTacToeBoard[2][0] = 'O';
                            break;
                        case 'H':
                            board.ticTacToeBoard[2][1] = 'O';
                            break;
                        case 'I':
                            board.ticTacToeBoard[2][2] = 'O';
                            break;
                        default:

                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    else
        {
            cout << "Sorry " << _name2;
            getUserName('B');                                                               // If none of the values are correct print out wrong value statement
            cout << " This is not a valid move." << endl;                                   // and send the user back to the invalid2 Marker.
            goto invalid2;
        }
    }
    checkForWin();                                                                       // Check for win - PROBLEM AREA
    board.printBoard();                                                                  // Print board for user1 visual
    userGo = 'G';                                                                        // swap to User1's Go.
}
}
```

I know I have used a load of magic numbers/characters and my code isn't going to be the most elegant as I am just learning, please any advice is much appreciated and also and mainly the reason I posted.

Why won't `checkForWin()` do what its told?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question but I made a refactor of your code here http://pastebin.com/fgnQy2w5 you'll need to change your "getUserName" routine to have names for 'O' and 'X' instead of 'A' and 'B', but it does everything in one loop rather than two loops, and I eliminated the iii/jjj loops entirely.

Comment: Cheers that is alot cleaner lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either add a member variable to `User` which represents the board, a global variable that can be seen by everything, or you need to make `checkForWin` take a board as a parameter.

```
checkForWin(Board& board)
{
     //Board board; // << remove this line
```

You would then pass the local board to checkForWin each time:

```
checkForWin(board);
```

A better design, though, would be to make `checkForWin` a member function of `Board` rather than `User` so that you would call:

```
board.checkForWin();
```

There are other design critiques and code changes I could recommend but that goes well beyond the scope of answering your question, better to let you absorb all of this and continue your studies at an appropriate pace :)

Comment: Thanks you for that i can confirm my first tictactoe game is running !!! bring on ALOT more study....checkForWin should of been in board in the first place lol duh moment....Thanks for the help :)

Comment: One more time thanks alot, cant wait till I get a firmer grasp on this....It is amazing :) silly i'm so excited about making tic tac toe but hey....baby steps...all the best

Answer (score 0):

In the `checkForWin` function, the variable `board` is a *local* variable. It exists only for that function and is default constructed.

***If*** you have a `User::board` member variable, or a global `board` variable, your local definition shadows and overrides the member/global variable.

Same in the `userGo` function.

Comment: Okay this is going to show how new to this I am...I understand that they are shadowing...So how would I go about giving my functions access to my array which is stored in class board as a public variable.

Comment: @Paul If You have a `User::board` member variable, then just don't declare the local variables. If the compiler will not find a local variable with the name `board` it will look for a member variable with that name (in effect it will try `this->board`) and if that's not found it will look for a global variable.

Comment: I have the array stored in class type board.

Comment: okay so now all functions live inside of class User. and It is reading it but now its just killing the program, it stops working when it runs the if statement